# Change page title via local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1, cms, local.xml

I have managed to change the title of the Register page with the following code in `local.xml`

```
<customer_account_create>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Create New Customer Account - Bomber Jacket</title></action>
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

How can I do something similar for a page like www.example.com/about-us.html ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Magento does not support page specific handles for CMS pages.**

You can only change title for all CMS pages via `local.xml` which is not what you want.

I suggest you use the backend when editing the CMS page you can add the following code to the **Layout Update XML** section:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>New Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

But I'm **pretty sure you don't have to use XML** and you can do that by changing the name of the CMS page.

Comment: The reason I want to do it this way is because it also changes the breadcrumbs if you change the name of the CMS page

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the URL specified is CMS page. In that case you can set the XML instructions in the CMS page itself, in: Design -> Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>About My shop</title></action>
</reference>
```